# support of a convolution

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $f$ in $L^1$, and $g$ in $L^p$. I want to prove that :

$Supp(f*g)\subset \overline{Supp(f)+supp(g)}$.

Remark: If f is mesurable function, Let $U_i$ to be the family of open in $E$, such that $f=0$ almost everywhere on $U_i$, and we set $U=\cup U_i$ then $f=0$ on $U$ almost everywhere, and we put $supp(f)=E$\ $U$.

Comment: You want closure of the sum.

Comment: You are right.. i will modify it!Thanks

Comment: user370927, what are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: To be honest i didn't have the idea to start.. I know how to prove that just for the continuos functions.